# How to retrieve a cell's height using Prawn & Prawnto?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I'm a little stuck on using Prawn/Prawnto to generate PDF documents.  The Prawn documentation has helped some, but the Prawnto documentation is seemingly offline these days.

I am trying to find a way to space text cells based on the previous cell's height.  Prawn has the methods to do this -- no problem, but the return value from doing pdf.cell (even though it generates a cell) is a Prawn bounding block -- essentially the page.

How can I do something similar to below and get the height of the cell, not of the bounding box?

```
offer = pdf.cell [220, 680], :text => @reward.offer, :width => 250, :font_size => 14
pitch = pdf.cell [220, offer.height - 20], :text => offer.height, :width => 250, :font_size => 12
rules = pdf.cell [220, pitch.height - 20], :text => pitch.height, :width => 250, :font_size => 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [prawnto rdoc](http://rdoc.info/projects/thorny-sun/prawnto)
- [prawnto homepage](http://www.cracklabs.com/prawnto)
- The [Table::Cell.text_area_height()](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/sandal/prawn-layout/blob/9e48a60f15efd7cbec48e42dc3ddd446149441ac/Prawn/Table/Cell.html#text_area_height-instance_method) method might be what you're looking for?

In this case, you're not really hitting prawnto, it just ties prawn into rails better.

All the layout and formatting is done in prawn and prawn-format and prawn-layout ([rdoc for those](http://rdoc.info/projects/search?q=prawn)). The docs are a little spaghetti-link at times.